# Content missing

Tags: 6

I inherited this production 6.36 website (20 or so multisite) that is heavily customized. Lately, it has begun to show weird behavior - like some js not working for non-admin users. One issue that is particularly worrying is losing pages. We have lost a page here and there over the last few months, but just this last week it has lost some 20 odd pages (as a band-aid we have been rebuilding those pages with the waybackmachine version of them).

I'm looking through the logs, but I am not sure what exactly to look for (I see http errors of page-not-found, but not much beyond that). We are on a LAMP stack, with PostgreSQL instead of mysql.

Anyone have any thoughts on what might be causing this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1):

If you're pulling information back from the Wayback Machine and you're losing data it sounds like step one is to make sure you have functional database backups. *Do that before you do anything else.*

[Drupal 6.36 has known security problems](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2016-001), in the past we've seen cases where attackers found ways to use attacks more broadly than initially documented. It's possible that's your problem.

That said, my experience is that the most common sources of missing content on Drupal 6 were either user error (deleting things they shouldn't), database corruption (less likely on Postgres than D6's default setup), or custom modules causing problems.

Since you say the site is heavily customized it is possible that you have custom code that attempts to alter pages under some condition and causes problems. Check your web server error logs to see if something is appearing there.

> **Note:** Drupal 6 is no longer supported by the community and Drupal 6 does not run well (at all?) on currently supported versions of PHP. *You should plan to update to Drupal 7 or Drupal 8 as soon as possible.*

Comment: We do have daily database backups, however, the entire D6 site is fairly fragile, and there is no backup environment to fall back on, in case a db backup doesn't succeed. I am simultaneously working on a D8 site, but in the meantime I have to support this site as well.

The watchdog list doesn't really show any "deleted" pages, just page-not-founds. Two follow up questions that I cannot find something helpful through a google search: 


one, is there a log of recently deleted pages somewhere? and two, I'm not a network expert, so how will i be able to tell if the site was "attacked".

Comment: Watchdog is the right place to look for deletions. Attacks are varied and can be hard to find. You don't need network expertise but you need to be willing to dig around the server and site structures a bit. Attackers are unlikely to delete at random (which is why I surmised other avenues are more likely), but it's possible particularly if they are using buggy code. Some common method of attack are to insert PHP commands into menu router table (not sure the D6 name but in D7 it's menu_router) or block table, or uploading PHP files (sometimes with .jpg extensions) into your files directory.